# Variar una query SELECT dependiendo de cuantos checkboxes haya seleccionados

Tags: javascript, html, mysql, nodejs

Estoy intentando hacer un `SELECT` que dependa de un `checkbox`, he conseguido poner los valores que yo quiero siempre y cuando seleccione TODOS los `checkbox` con `NodeJs`.

Es decir:

```
<form method="post" action="selectDb">
    <div>
    <input type="checkbox" name="nom" value="nombre">Nombre
    <input type="checkbox" name='ape' value="apellido">Apellido
    <input type="checkbox" name='s_a' value="s_apellido">Segundo apellido
</div>
    <br><br>
    <input type="submit" name="Enviar">

</form>
```

Tengo este formulario con los `checkbox` en el `front-end`, y si selecciono todos, me sale correctamente, siendo lo siguiente el código del `back-end`:

```
app.post('/selectDb', (req, res) => {
    let slNom = req.body.nom;
    let slApe = req.body.ape;
    let slSAp = req.body.s_a;

    pool.query('SELECT ' + slNom + ', ' + slApe + ', ' + slSAp + ' FROM Pruebas', function(error, result){
        if (error)  {
            console.log(error)
        }
        else{
            console.log(result);
        }
    });
    res.sendfile('./index.html');
});
```

El caso es que necesitaría poder cambiar ese SELECT, y hacer que, si por ejemplo elijo mostrar solo los apellidos (`apellido` y `s_apellido`), el valor `nombre` no lo incluya dentro del `SELECT`.

Se que hay un comando que verifica si es `checked` o no, pero no encuentro forma de poder implementarlo aquí.

El caso es que, los valores funcionan correctamente, ya que si hago un `console.log` con `(result)` me verifica todas las columnas de la SQL en la consola.

**[EDIT]**

He cambiado la forma de hacerlo, quizá de peor resultado, pero es así tal y como lo tengo ahora en el `back-end`:

```
// POST SELECT
app.post('/selectDb', (req, res) => {
    let slNom = req.body.nom || null;
    let slApe = req.body.ape || null;
    let slSAp = req.body.s_a || null;

    /*pool.query('SELECT ' + slNom + ', ' + slApe + ', ' + slSAp + ' FROM Pruebas', function(error, result){
        if (error)  {
            console.log(error)
        }
        else{
            console.log(result);
        }
    });*/

    pool.query('SELECT(nombre, apellido, s_apellido) VALUES(?, ?, ?) FROM Pruebas', [slNom, slApe, slSAp], function(error, result){
        if (error)  {
            console.log(error);
        }   else    {
            console.log(result);
        }
    })
    res.sendfile('./index.html');
});
```

(Tengo comentado la primera forma de hacerlo para que no funcione pero no se me olvide)

**[EDIT : 2]**

También probé a sacar los valores `undefined` como `NULL`, y funciona, pero tendría que encontrar una forma concreta de no concatenar los valores checkeados con los valores NULL.

Answer (score 1):

Tus checkboxes tienen el propósito de decirle al backend cuáles campos quieres traer o listar, de manera que debieras mandarlos como un conjunto en vez de datos independientes. Por jemplo:

```
<input type="checkbox" name="campos[]" value="nombre">Nombre
<input type="checkbox" name="campos[]" value="apellido">Apellido
<input type="checkbox" name="campos[]" value="s_apellido">Segundo apellido
```

Tal que en el backend puedas poner:

```
app.post('/selectDb', (req, res) => {
       let campos = req.body.campos;
       ...

});
```

Y `campos` contenga, por ejemplo `['nombre','s_apellido']`. Para que el backend reciba esa data en un arreglo tienes que usar un middleware como 'body-parser'  :

```
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');

app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true}));

app.post('/selectDb', (req, res) => {
       let campos = req.body.campos;
       ...
});
```

Por otro lado, cuando le das al usuario la facultad de elegir los campos, siempre tienes que pensar que del otro lado hay un hacker que quiere encriptarte la base de datos y pedirte rescate en bitcoins. Tienes que sanitizar lo recibido, por ejemplo con una lista blanca:

```
const allowedFields = ['id', 'nombre', 'apellido', 's_apellido'],
    campos = req.body.campos,
    camposValidos = req.body.campos.filter(campo => {
      return allowedFields.includes(campo);
    });
```

Y eso ya es más seguro de interpolar, ojo que la query va envuelta en backticks, no en comillas simples:

```
  pool.query(`SELECT ${camposValidos.join(', ')} FROM Pruebas`,...
```

Hay paquetes que envuelven la conexión transparentemente y sanitizan esta clase de casos de uso, como [@atdatabases/mysql](https://www.atdatabases.org/docs/sql), donde podrías hacer:

```
 const createConnectionPool = require('@databases/mysql'),
 {sql} = require('@databases/mysql'),
 pool = createConnectionPool(
          'mysql://test-user:password@localhost:3306/test-db',
      );
```

Y más abajo ejecutar casi lo mismo pero sanitizado por este wrapper. Declaro el handler como async para aprovechar que este wrapper devuelve promesas

```
app.post('/selectDb', async (req, res) => {
  const allowedFields = ['id', 'nombre', 'apellido', 's_apellido'],
    campos = req.body.campos,
    camposValidos = req.body.campos.filter(campo => {
      return allowedFields.includes(campo);
    });

    let result = await pool.query(sql`SELECT ${camposValidos.join(', ')} FROM Pruebas`);
});
```

(efectivamente, dice 'sql' antes de la query misma)